# Firebase Phone authentication cant link with Email authentication

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to link a Phone account with an Email account, but I have trouble linking it with the `linkWithAuth()` method.

Here is my method to link two accounts.

```
private void linkPhone(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
AuthFireSingleTon.instanceOfAuth().linkWithCredential(credential)
        .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.wtf(TAG, "linked: SUCCESSFULLY");
                } else {
                    Log.wtf(TAG, "link failed PHONE AUTH " + task.getException().getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
}
```

And the logcat output

> link failed PHONE AUTH User has already been linked to the given provider.

Even though I deleted all the accounts on my Firebase dashboard it still says this error.

> user has already been linked to the given provider

Comment: After you delete the user in the console, sign out and try again. The check could be client side and not going to the server.